# If I am Using Zend Grid to display table, how can I pass value from another page to the controller without using ajax?

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, grid

In ZEND if I am deploying a table using grid, will I be able to pass value from another html page without using AJAX to the controller. If not how to pass the value to the controller??

Example:

i have viewdata.phtml and viewdataController.php, i have buttons on the phtml page, clicking on which the data displayed will change. The query and grid codes are in the controller's action body. So i need to pass the value to the action body to put condition according to which the display data will change.

Any suggestion and solution is invited.

Comment: What have you tried/researched, show a minimum understanding of the problem to be solved

Comment: The question in simple words is : Without using ajax how can I pass value to a controller, if the value is dynamic... hope its a bit clear this time.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I totally understand and I'm not sure exactly what you tried yet but here is a guess at it.

If you don't want to use AJAX, you will need to reload the page, there is no way to refresh only part of the page using only PHP (see client-side scripting vs server-side).  In your view, you can use links to pass the wanted data:

```
<a href="<?=$this->url(array(
  'controller' => 'viewdata',
  'action' => 'viewdata',
  'param1' => 'value1',
  'param2' => 'param2');?>"><button type="button">Click here</button></a>
```